# VB.NET how to check if a form already exists?

Tags: vb.net

for a chat client i want to create a new form instance for each user who is writing a private message and check if the user has an open instance already or not before creating an instance.

i tried to check it using dictionary but i could not get it to work..

```vb
Dim convs As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim nf As New FrmDialog()


convs.Add(WritePUser, WritePMessage)
nf.Show()

If convs.ContainsKey(WritePUser) Then
    MsgBox("im already open")
Else
    nf.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Firstly, please look at the preview of your question and don't submit it if the formatting is a mess. I first looked at your question on a phone and, thanks to the pointless wad of leading whitespace, I could read your code without scrolling sideways. Don't make your question harder to read for no good reason.

Comment: uh okay i understand. next time i will be more careful when posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know whether the code you posted is in one place in your app or multiple but it doesn't make sense to declare and create the `Dictionary` where you use it. If you do that then you'll be creating a new `Dictionary` every time so you'll never be able to see previously-created forms. You need to create one `Dictionary` and assign it to a field, i.e. a class-level variable. You then use that one and only `Dictionary` every time. The values in the `Dictionary` should also be forms, not `Strings`, so that you can access the existing form. You also need to either remove forms from the `Dictionary` when they close or else check whether the existing form is disposed. The latter is probably the simpler option.

```vb
Private dialoguesByUserName As New Dictionary(Of String, FrmDialog)
```

Then:

```vb
Dim dialogue As FrmDialog

If Not dialoguesByUserName.TryGetValue(userName, dialogue) OrElse
   dialogue.IsDisposed Then
    'Either there is no existing form or the existing form has been closed.
    dialogue = New FrmDialog
    dialoguesByUserName[userName] = dialogue
    dialogue.Show()
Else
    'Focus the existing form.
    dialogue.Activate()
End If
```

Comment: i got it to work now using your example and informations you gave me. big thanks and best wishes!

Comment: @xeno, while I appreciate the sentiment, comments like that are discouraged on this site. Up-votes and accepting answers is all the acknowledgement and thanks that's required.